# Regarding SOLID principles, in a lead/senior position how should you judge other's code?

Tags: oop, solid-principles

I'm a little confused about promoting SOLID between team members. Some argue that SOLID is a tool which can be followed only if there are demand for building it under SOLID principles, like TDD development. They argue that if it's a simple application, you can just kind of "go horse" that it will be as good as a SOLID application. Given that, whenever they start a project alone, they code by their own will.

Let's give a scenario: your framework provides a IoC and you keep creating objects with new operator inside classes constructors. The reason for that may be because it's fast to just type "new" rather than describing the object dependencies in the IoC or creating a factory. Perhaps the class needs a configuration, so they get this from inside the object tying the object to a helper which gets an environment variable instead of injecting and making the object agnostic.

They say, this is not wrong, SOLID is not something you should follow at every scenario.

How do you improve your skills in a team like that? How do you get used to write well formed code, based on principles if people seem to think that's just another tool like a library and you shouldn't care that much about it?

Comment: (1) It's time for you to find a better team, or job. (2) It's time for me to 'close' this as 'off-topic'.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to [Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) SE.

Comment: I pity the fools who think that the whole of OO can be abbreviated to five design principles without any regard to the many finer details of the OO paradigm: abstraction, encapsulation, cohesion, decoupling, messages versus methods, inheritance, polymorphism, generalisation, interfaces, etc.

It's like limiting oneself to reading the synopsis on the back of a book instead of the book itself.

Comment: Learn from experts. Experts publish books, and blogs, and youtube videos, and occasionally even StackOverflow answers. You don't need to work with experts to learn from experts.